# scanning .o file in xvi32

Tags: c++, hex, bit

can someone explain how [this hexadecimal view of the .o file in xvi32](http://s3762.chomikuj.pl/ChomikImage.aspx?k=1367397&t=634717640201407836&id=822200870&vid=1635116473&loc=PL)
corresponds to the data in .cpp? i.e. what do numbers like '/18 '/65 '/139 and ".rdata" means?
when I open corresponding exe for example, then I see that files are quite similarly with slight differences, at least this beginning. But in particular: why in exe this ".rdata" becomes ".data"?
here is the .cpp from which this .o has been created:

```
    // exercise_for.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <map>

#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>

#include <limits>

struct myStruct{
    int a;
    double b;
    virtual void func()=0;
    void f(){};
};
struct sB{virtual void g()=0;};
struct myStruct2:sB{
    void f(){};
    void g(){std::cout<<"\nmyStruct2";}
};
struct myStruct3:sB{
    void f(int const &in){a=in;};
    void g(){std::cout<<"\nmyStruct3";};
    myStruct3():a(0){};
    int show(){return a;};
private:
    int a;
};

class myC : public myStruct{
    int i;
    void func(){};
};

std::map<std::string,int> histogram;
void record(const std::string& in ){
    histogram[in]++;
}
void print(const std::pair<const std::string,int>& in ){
    std::cout<<(in.first)<<" "<<in.second<<"\n";
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout<<"largest float:"<<std::numeric_limits<float>::max()<<
        "\nchar is signed:"<<std::numeric_limits<char>::is_signed<<
        "\nlargest int:"<<std::numeric_limits<int>::max()<<
        "\nlargest double:"<<std::numeric_limits<double>::max()<<
        "\nlargest short int:"<<std::numeric_limits<short int>::max()<<
        "\nlargest long int:"<<std::numeric_limits<long int>::max()<<"\n\n";

    for(int i=0;i<10;++i){
        std::cout<<++i;
    }

    myC mC;
    myStruct2 m;
    myStruct3 n;
    std::cout<<"n: "<<n.show();
    m.f();
    n.f(4);
    std::cout<<"\nn: "<<n.show();

    std::cout<<"\nmem_fun";
    std::list<sB*> myList;
    myList.push_back(&m);
    myList.push_back(&n);
    std::for_each(myList.begin(),myList.end(),std::mem_fun(&sB::g));
    std::list<sB*>::iterator it=myList.begin(); 

    std::istream_iterator<std::string> ii(std::cin);
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> eos;
    std::for_each(ii,eos,record);
    int i=0xffff;
    std::string z;
    std::cout<<"\n\nprinting: sizeof(int)="<<sizeof(int)<<"  i:"<<i<<"\n";
    int* i_ptr;
    std::cout<<"sizeof(int*)="<<sizeof(i_ptr)<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"sizeof(double)="<<sizeof(double)<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"sizeof(double*)="<<sizeof(double*)<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"sizeof(string)="<<sizeof(z)<<"\n";
    float fl=1000+1.6+1.6+1.6+1.6;
    std::cout<<"\nf:"<<fl;
    std::for_each(histogram.begin(),histogram.end(),print);

    std::vector<std::string> sL;
    std::string s("spadaj");
    sL.push_back(s);
    std::copy(sL.begin(),sL.end(),std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
    std::ofstream f("myFile.txt"); 
    std::copy(sL.begin(),sL.end(),std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(f, " "));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little like looking at a hamburger, and asking "What part of the cow did this come from?" A given hamburger may contain meat from half a dozen different parts of each of three or four different cows.

To get much of anywhere, you probably want to start from something a bit more intelligent than a plain hex-dump of an object file (or executable). You probably want to use a disassembler than can at least let you look more or less directly at the output as assembly language source code. Without that, you need some fairly intimate knowledge of the object file format to even know which parts to really look at, and which parts are things like relocation records, or possibly even just padding between sections (i.e., completely meaningless). It's obviously possible to do that, but unless you have no choice, it's rarely a gratifying way to spend your time.

It's not the best disassembler around (by any means) but the Microsoft Windows SDK includes a tool named `dumpbin` that can disassemble code in an executable using the `/disasm` flag. If you do some looking around, there are various other disassemblers available as well. If you're willing to spend some money, I'd recommend [IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/) as the best I've used. It's definitely *not* free or even particularly inexpensive, but worth every penny if you're going to do this much.

Comment: I know that it is like this cow, but I like looking at this cow and mulling "What part of the cow did this come from?"  : D